# how to style geojson based on properties

Tags: python, leaflet, geojson

I have a geojson file and I am trying to colour my data based on there properties.My data type is MultiPolygon.

However, I am getting an invalid syntax on line 2 saying "style: function(feature){"

```
  L.geoJSON(gjson,{
  style: function(feature){
    switch (feature.properties.Traveltime) {
        case '10800': return {color: "#ff0000"};
        case '1800': return {color: "#0000ff"};
        case '3600': return {color: "#0000ff"};
        case '5400': return {color: "#ff0000"};
        case '7200': return {color: "#ff0000"};
    }
}   

}).addTo(map_Baseline);
```

any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You do know that code is JavaScript.... You tagged ' python'...

Answer (score 0):

I would try something along the lines of:

1. load the geoJSON with standard style
2. create a function to be called right after, looking something like this

   ```
    function propertyDependentStyle(feature){
        switch (feature.properties.Traveltime) {
            case '10800': gjson.setStyle({color: "#ff0000"});
            case '1800': gjson.setStyle({color: "#0000ff"});
            case '3600': gjson.setStyle({color: "#0000ff"});
            case '5400': gjson.setStyle({color: "#ff0000"});
            case '7200': gjson.setStyle({color: "#ff0000"});
        }
   ```

   }

This is just from the top of my head, not really tested, so you might still have to do some tinkering or debugging.